# Menú pierde estilos al mostrar llamado de base de datos vacía

Tags: php, html

Al darle click a un link del menú y no encontrar información en la base de datos o no contener ningún valor, muestra un echo con un mensaje, es ahí cuando el menú pierde los estilos y muestra el menú como el de la imagen siguiente:
[image: Menú sin estilo]

Pero si encuentra alguna información en la base de datos para mostrar en pantalla, la muestra sin alterar el menú, sólo ocurre la pérdida de estilo al no encontrar datos y mostrar el mensaje insertado.
Si es por no encontrar ningún valor en la base de datos, como podría hacer para mostrar un mensaje diciendo que no hay datos y mantener el menú?

Soy nuevo en php, css y html alguien con experiencia podría ayudarme?

```
 <!--Inicio Menu-->
    <?php include 'maq/menu.inc' ?>
    <!--Fin Menu-->
    
<?php
    require_once("sesion.class.php");
    
    $sesion = new sesion();
    $usuario = $sesion->get("l0g1n");
    
    if( $usuario == false ){    
        header("Location: index.php");      
    }
    else 
    {
?>

<?php

include("conexion.php");

$consulta1="select * from l0g1n where email='$usuario'";
$resul1=mysqli_query($conex, $consulta1) or die(mysqli_error());
$cont1=mysqli_num_rows($resul1);

    if($cont1==0){ 

    
    }
    else
    {
    $consulta2= mysqli_query($conex,"SELECT dni FROM l0g1n where email='$usuario'");
        if ($resul2 = mysqli_fetch_row($consulta2)) 
        {
        $usu2 = trim($resul2[0]);
        
        $consulta3= mysqli_query($conex,"SELECT email FROM as1g_c0d where dni='$usu2'");
            if ($resul3 = mysqli_fetch_row($consulta3)) 
            {
            $usuario2 = trim($resul3[0]);
            }
        }
    }
?>

<?php
include("conexion.php");
$primerabusq = array();  

function GuardarDatos ($resultbusq) {
        if ($resultbusq !=NULL) {
        
        }       
    }
$link = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass");
mysqli_select_db($link,"nombre bd");
$sqltabla1= mysqli_query ($link, "select codigot from as1g_c0d where dni='$usu2'");

while($consulta1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltabla1)) 
{ 
   GuardarDatos($consulta1);
  
   $primerabusq[] = $consulta1['codigot'];  
  
}  
?>


<?php
include("conexion.php");
$segundabusq = array();  

function GuardarDatos2 ($resultbusq2) {
        if ($resultbusq2 !=NULL) {
        
        }       
    }
$link = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass");
mysqli_select_db($link,"nombre bd");
$sqltabla2= mysqli_query ($link, "select codigot from jueg0_r3f3 where nivel='Cerrado'");

while($consulta2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltabla2)) 
{ 
   GuardarDatos2($consulta2);
 
   $segundabusq[] = $consulta2['codigot'];  
}  
?>


<?php

include("conexion.php");


$final="select * from tabla where dnip='$usu2'";
$resp=mysqli_query($conex, $final) or die(mysqli_error());
$fff=mysqli_num_rows($resp);
if($fff==0){ 

}
else
{
    
$final2="select * from encuesta where dni='$usu2'";
$resp2=mysqli_query($conex, $final2) or die(mysqli_error());
$fff2=mysqli_num_rows($resp2);
if($fff2==0)
{ 
include("cuestionario.html");
return false;   
}
}
?>


<?php
$tercerabusq = array(); 
foreach ($primerabusq as $value1){
$encontrado=false;

    foreach ($segundabusq as $value2){
        if ($value1 == $value2){
            $encontrado=true;
            $break;
            }
    }
    
    if ($encontrado == false){
  
     $tercerabusq[] = $value1;  
    }
}
?>

<?php
$nacional2= 'No Participa';

include("conexion.php");
if (empty ($tercerabusq[0])){
  $a='nada';
}
else{
     $a=$tercerabusq[0];
}
if (empty ($tercerabusq[1])){
  $b='nada';
}
else{
     $b=$tercerabusq[1];
}
if (empty ($tercerabusq[2])){
   $c='nada';
}
else{
    $c=$tercerabusq[2];
}
  
 
  
$busquedanacional= mysqli_query($conex, "select paquete from p4qu3t3 where codigot='$a'");
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($busquedanacional)) {
$nacional1 = trim($row[0]);
    if ($nacional1=='Nacional'){
    $nacional2= $a;
    }
    else {
    $busquedanacional1= mysqli_query($conex, "select paquete from p4qu3t3 where codigot='$b'");
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($busquedanacional1)) {
        $nacional1 = trim($row[0]);
            if ($nacional1=='Nacional'){
            $nacional2= $b;
            }
            else{
            $busquedanacional2= mysqli_query($conex, "select paquete from p4qu3t3 where codigot='$c'");
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($busquedanacional2)) {
                $nacional1 = trim($row[0]);
                    if ($nacional1=='Nacional'){
                    $nacional2= $c;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php

include("conexion.php");

$sql="select * from as1g_c0d where email='$usuario2'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conex, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$fila=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

    if($fila==0){ 

    
    }
    else
    {
    $query= mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT nombres FROM as1g_c0d where email='$usuario2'");
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) 
        {
        $id = trim($row[0]);
        
            if  ($nacional2== 'No Participa'){
                echo '<br> <blockquote> <blockquote><h1 style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #de0400; font-size: 2em"> Aún No Estas Participando<br>  ';
                echo ' <h3 style="font-family: sans-serif; color: #005ec9">==> participa ya! <a href="Paquete_Nacional.php"></a><br></h3>';
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $sql2="select * from jueg0_r3f3 where codigot='$nacional2'";
                $cs=mysqli_query($conex, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error());
                        
                        while($resul=mysqli_fetch_array($cs)){
                        $nivel=$resul[0];
                        $codigop=$resul[1];
                        $codigor1=$resul[2];
                        $codigor2=$resul[3];
                        $codigor3=$resul[4];
                        }
            }
        }
    }
 ?>

 <?php
 
 include("conexion.php");

$sql="select * from as1g_c0d where email='$usuario2'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conex, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$fila=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

    if($fila==0){ 

    
    }
    else
    {
    $query= mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT paquete FROM p4qu3t3 where codigot='$nacional2'");
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) 
        {
        $paquete = trim($row[0]);
 }
 
 }
 
  ?>
  
  
<?php

include("conexion.php");

$c1= mysqli_query ($conex, "select nombres from as1g_c0d where codigo='$codigop'");
if ($r1 = mysqli_fetch_row($c1))
{
$cp = trim($r1[0]);
}

$c2= mysqli_query ($conex, "select nombres from as1g_c0d where codigo='$codigor1'");
if ($r2 = mysqli_fetch_row($c2)){ 
$cr1 = trim($r2[0]);
} 
else{
    $cr1 =" "; 

}


$c3= mysqli_query ($conex, "select nombres from as1g_c0d where codigo='$codigor2'");
if ($r3 = mysqli_fetch_row($c3)){ 
$cr2 = trim($r3[0]);
} 
else{
    $cr2 =" "; 

}

$c4= mysqli_query ($conex, "select nombres from as1g_c0d where codigo='$codigor3'");
if ($r4 = mysqli_fetch_row($c4)){ 
$cr3 = trim($r4[0]);
} 
else{
    $cr3 =" "; 

}
 ?>
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TC</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <div class="container">
        <style type="text/css">
        
            body {
            color: black;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            }
        
            h1{
            padding-top: 30px;
            font-size: 19px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color:#cca300;
            }
        
            h2{
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align:center;
            color:#cca300;
            padding-top: 17px;
            }
            
            h3{
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align:center;
            color:#995c00;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            padding-bottom: 30px;
            
            font-weight: 600;
            font-variant: small-caps;
            }
            
            h4{
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align:left;
            
            font-family: sans-serif;
            
            font-weight: 600;
            font-variant: small-caps;
            }
        
            .form-style-2{
            
            max-width: 900px;
            padding: 10px 10px 8px 10px;
            font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
    
            .relleno{
            background-color: black;
            border-radius: 27px 27px 27px 27px;
            -moz-border-radius: 27px 27px 27px 27px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 27px 27px 27px 27px;
            border: 4px inset #8c8c8c;
            width: 550px; 
            height: 280px;
            }
    
            .form-style-2-heading{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: italic;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-size: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 3px;
            text-align: right;
            }
        
            table{
                
            font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
            font-size: 12px;    
            margin: 12px;
            width: 500px; 
            height: 205px;
            }
        
            .tg{
            border-collapse:separate;
            border-spacing:20px;
            border-color:#aaa;
            }
        
            .tg td{
            font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            padding:12px 12px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:1px;
            overflow:hidden;
            word-break:normal;
            border-color:#aaa;
            color:#332900;
            border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
            border: 3px double #000000; 
            background: #f0c968;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0c968 0%, #d49537 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f0c968), color-stop(100%, #d49537));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0c968 0%, #d49537 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f0c968 0%, #d49537 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0c968 0%, #d49537 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0c968 0%, #d49537 100%);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0c968', endColorstr='#d49537', GradientType=0 );
            }
        
            .tg th{
            font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight:normal;
            padding:12px 12px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:1px;
            overflow:hidden;
            word-break:normal;
            border-color:#aaa;
            color:#332900; 
            border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
            border: 3px double #000000; 
            background: #f0c968;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0c968 0%, #d49537 100%);
            background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f0c968), color-stop(100%, #d49537));
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f0c968 0%, #d49537 100%);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f0c968 0%, #d49537 100%);
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f0c968 0%, #d49537 100%);
            background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f0c968 0%, #d49537 100%);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0c968', endColorstr='#d49537', GradientType=0 );
            }
        
            .tg .tg-baqh{
            font-size: 18px;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:top;
            padding-top: 22px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: italic;
            }
        
            .tg .tg-yw4l{
            font-size: 18px;
            text-align:center;
            vertical-align:top;
            padding-top: 22px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: italic;
            }
        
            .form-style-2 input[type=submit],.form-style-2 input[type=button]{
            border: none;
            padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
            background: #FF8500;
            color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
            -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #DADADA;
            border-radius: 3px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
            -moz-border-radius: 3px;
            }
        
            .form-style-2 input[type=submit]:hover,.form-style-2 input[type=button]:hover{
            background: #EA7B00;
            color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </div>
</head>
    
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-style-2">
        <center>
            <div class="form-style-2-heading"> <h1> Bienvenid@  <?php echo $id; ?>
            </div>
        
            <form name="fe" action="" method="post">
                        
            <?php

            include("conexion.php");


            $final="select * from tabla where codigop='$codigop'";
            $resp=mysqli_query($conex, $final) or die(mysqli_error());
            $fff=mysqli_num_rows($resp);
            if($fff==0)

            { 
            }
            else
            {
            echo "<br><br><h3>¡Felicitaciones</h3>";
            echo ' <h4>Gracias por participar, <a href="encuesta.php">Continúa Aquí!</a><br></h4>'; 
            }

            ?>
            
            <h3>Tipo de Junta: <?php echo $paquete; ?></h3>
            
                <div class="relleno">
                <h2>Tabla de Premios</h2>
                
                    <table class="tg"> 
                        <tr>
                        <?php

                        if ($id == $cr1)
                        {
                        echo "<th style='border:2px double #0066ff' class='tg-baqh'>$cr1</th>";
                        }    
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "<th class='tg-baqh'>$cr1</th>";
                        }
                        ?>
                        
                        <?php
                        if ($id == $cr2)
                        {
                        echo "<th style='border:2px double #0066ff' class='tg-yw4l'>$cr2</th>";
                        }    
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "<th class='tg-yw4l'>$cr2</th>";
                        }
                        ?>
                        
                        
                        <?php

                        if ($id == $cr3)
                        {
                        echo "<th style='border:2px double #0066ff' class='tg-yw4l'>$cr3</th>";
                        }    
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "<th class='tg-yw4l'>$cr3</th>";
                        }
                        
                        ?>
                        
                        
                        
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        
                        <?php

                        if ($id == $cp)
                        {
                        
                        
                        echo "<td style='border:2px double #0066ff' class='tg-baqh' colspan='3'>$cp</td>";
                        }    
                        else 
                        {
                            echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='3'>$cp</td>";
                        }
                        ?>
                        
                        
                        
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    
                </div>
                
            </form>
            </center>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
    
    <?php 
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba quitando el `return false;`que tienes justo donde incluyes esa leyenda (linea donde verificas `ìf ($nacional2=='No Participa')` si no me equivoco).

Comment: Mucha gracias por tu ayuda, me funcionó perfecto.